# file upload validation with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to make validation for file upload. I am doing it using AJAX, but there is a problem during validation.

```
jQuery('#form-docs').submit(function()
{
    var url = $(this).attr("action");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        data: jQuery('#form-docs').serialize(),
        datatype: "json",
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            jQuery('#ajax-loading').show();
            jQuery(".validation-error-inline").hide();
        }
    })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                $('#validation-div').empty()
                if (data.validation_failed === 1)
                {
                    var arr = data.errors;

                   alert(arr);
                }
                else {
                    window.location = data.redirect_to;
                }
            })
    return false;
});
```

controller

```
 if ((Input::file('owner_cert_doc') != NULL) || (Input::file('sgs_doc') != NULL) || (Input::file('tpl_doc') != NULL) || (Input::file('kasko_doc') != NULL) || (Input::file('drive_permis_doc') != NULL)) {
            $car_id = Input::get('id_value');
            $id = DB::select('select id from insur_docs where car_id=?', array($car_id));
            $id_insert = DB::select('select id from insurdocs_inserts where car_id=?', array($car_id));
            $options = ['gs' => ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain']];
            $ctx = stream_context_create($options);
            //ownership certificate documentations
            $random_owner = str_random(5);
            if (Input::hasFile('owner_cert_doc')) {
                $owner_input = Input::get('owner_cert_doc');
                $owner_cert_doc = $_FILES['owner_cert_doc']['name'];
                if (false == rename($_FILES['owner_cert_doc']['tmp_name'], 'gs://docs_upload/' .
                                $random_owner . '_' . $owner_cert_doc, $ctx)) {
                    die('Could not rename.');
                }
            }
 $car = InsurDoc::find($id[0]->id);
            if (Input::hasFile('owner_cert_doc')) {
                $car->owner_cert_doc = 'gs://docs_upload/' . $random_owner . '_' . $owner_cert_doc;
            }
$car->save();

            return Redirect::to('car/' . $car_id);
        } else {        
                $response_values = array(
                    'validation_failed' => 1,
                    'errors' => Lang::get('messages.invalid_upload'),
                );
                return Response::json($response_values);   
        }
```

The problem is that when click submit nothing happens. console shows:`"Post 400 (bad request)`
Instead if replace else with dd('error'); It displays "error".

Comment: `jQuery('#form-docs').serialize()` will not send any files to the server when making the AJAX call.

Comment: but at other validations this works. Only for file upload doesn't

Comment: Yes, that's because you cannot upload files using AJAX. You might use the native XmlHttpRequest object and if the client browser supports uploading files in HTML5, you will be able to achieve that. Otherwise if the client is using older browsers you will have to resort to some legacy techniques such as Flash or hidden iframes.

Comment: what other option is there for showing validation without AJAX? I just want to display a message if no file is submitted

Comment: There aren't much options. It will be browser dependent and the capabilities it supports. You will have to detect the client browser capabilities and perform the validation if it supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Darin Dimitrov's comments are correct and to that end you can use http://www.plupload.com/ or similar plugin to make AJAX file upload. There are examples of frontend and backend in their documentation. Pretty simple:)

Comment: I don't want to change all file upload, I had some difficulties till I realised it. Now I just want to display an error message when no file is uploaded. What other options do I have ? Without AJAX

Comment: confusing question. if it was a simple php application i would say - something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp, but you seem to be using some kind of framework and probably have to use it's methods for displaying errors on validate.